# Backbone.Marionette - Accessing variables in the ItemView template or CompositeView template

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Here i want to access a variable or a list of variables which is passed when initalizing a new view from its corresponding template.

## Code example

Creating a list view

```
@Taskit.module "Tasks.List", (List, Taskit, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
    class List.NewTask extends Taskit.Views.ItemView
        template: JST["backbone/taskit/tasks/tasks/list/_templates/new_task"]
```

Template for the above list view

```
<div id="new-task-form">
</div>
```

Initializing the ItemView

```
view = new Taskit.Tasks.List.NewTask
    project_id: "project_id"
```

Here my question is how can i access the "project_id" variable from its template.

```
<%= project_id %> #is not working
```

In Backbone it can be achieved by

```
$(@el).html(@template({task: @model, project_id: "project_id"}))
```

## how to do it in Marionette.js?

Answer (score 12):

You can provide your own method to serialize data:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#itemview-serializedata

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  serializeData: function(){
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    data.project_id = this.project_id;

    return data;
  }
});
```

Comment: There is templateHelpers attribute in Marionette views which can be used to pass data to its template. To pass data to ItemView u can use itemViewOptions attribute of collection/composite view

Comment: +1 for ``templateHelpers``. Docs: http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers

Comment: Marionette core here, you should be using `templateHelpers` if you want additional data in your view. Use `serializeData` if you need to transform the data in a model or collection.